# How to scan new gmail, extract data, and post to spreadsheet on google site?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, gmail

I receive daily email reports from a SCADA computer regarding water levels in our reservoir, and would like to extract this data, append it to a google spreadsheet, and display it on our google site.  I have made several attempts at automating this procedure with php and appengine, but feel that there should be a simpler solution, such as using a daily triggered gmail filter and js script.  Can anyone provide some guidance or example reference?  Thanks

PS: The daily emails have several data file attachments (.csv format) that I will eventually want to process into my spreadsheet, but for right now I simply want to scrape the desired data (gallons pumped) from the text of the message body.  Although perhaps trivial with apps script, I would appreciate links to script examples or references to get me started.

Comment: well that's super broad. what format is the email report in?

Comment: pretty trivial if using google apps script

Answer (score 1):

The [Save Gmail](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-emails-and-attachmen/nflmnfjphdbeagnilbihcodcophecebc) add-on that writes your Gmail messages to a Google Sheet and also saves them to Google Drive. It might help. (disclaimer: I am the author)